# Integrating C# code in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I have an Excel file with many different, but very similar, userforms.

When I click on a cell in my worksheet a specific userform will open according to the cell text.

I wanted to know if there is a way to add a C# form to Excel which will behave as a userform? Since the visual studio interface is much simpler and a lot more generic than VB.

I know you can create C# add-in's for excel, but these are used to add buttons, ribbons, etc.
what I need is a way to add a dll which will be activated when clicking on a cell, this dll must be easy to update, and it should not include installation (like the add-in's).

Comment: Yes and no. You can create a C# library usable from VBA (then Excel too) but it must be a COM library so it needs installation (COM objects must be registered with regasm).

Comment: If you are using VS and C#, hasn't your project outgrown Excel? Sounds like you need a database, not a visual calculator.

Answer (score 0):

I got the following answer from a different forum:

You have some possibilities

1) Actually Excel (and practically all Office application) support Add-ins. Thus you could make a legacy excel add-in. There are several tutorials out there, but this is not the simplest one.

2) An other interesting approach exceldna.codeplex.com/[^]

3) You can call managed code from excel vba, but it is not the wisest one, since vba runs in a rather undeterministic way. Start here: richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/15/…^]

4) Interop Forms Toolkit[^] might be also an alternative – user2134909 2 mins ago edit

I haven't thoroughly examined them, but they seem promising